# url rewriting in php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hai

I have one more doubt in apache mod_rewrite.
 I want to rewrite the url 
mydomain/index.php?category=1&id=1
To
mydomain/index/category/1/id/1
How I write rule in .htaccess

And what is the link that i have to give inside the a tag

Please give me a solution..

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but worth a shot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/category/([0-9]+)/id/([0-9]+)$ index.php?category=$1&id=$2
```

Your URLs can look exactly like the way you mentioned:

```
Category 1
<a href="index/category/1/id/1">Product 1</a>
<a href="index/category/1/id/2">Product 2</a>
Category 2
<a href="index/category/2/id/3">Product 3</a>
<a href="index/category/2/id/4">Product 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<a>` tags you will use the nice link, that is `category/1/id/1` (that's exactly why you're using `mod_rewrite`, to be able to use nice URLs!)

As for the rule, try something like (untested):

```
RewriteRule category/(.*)/id/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Actually I would rather use

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

So you can call directly `mydomain/1/1` but you got the idea I hope

**EDIT**: the `&%{QUERY_STRING}` part is not necessary for what you asked, but I generally include it in case I want to pass any extra parameter to the page.