# How can I remove the .php extension using .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need for my .htaccess file to take away the .php file extension and replace it with just a trailing slash.

Also, I have a profile.php page which will normally be visited with a numeric querystring parameter, like "`profile.php?id=3`".

So on top of replacing extensions with slashes, how do I make "`profile.php?id=3`" look like "`profile/3/`"?

So far all I have is the first line:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [url rewriting in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896015/url-rewriting-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're so new... you really should [read the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
// if not a file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
// if not a directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
// pass all params back to index.php
// QSA stands for query string append
// L stands for last rule
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this will do what you want. Now don't be lazy. Read the manual!

Comment: Pointless telling him not to be lazy after you've done the work for him :P

Comment: @MrXexxed, you're right... you're right... shouldn't have! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```